# Spock testing with Android

Tags: android, gradle, spock

I'm trying to run spock tests in my android studio but I can't manage to get this to work.

I added the groovy and the spock dependencies inside the module gradle file and applied the dependency inside the project build gradle.

The error I'm getting while running the spock test is this:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugUnitTestGroovyWithGroovyc'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

The test is located at `src\test\groovy\` directory

Here is the module-level gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'groovyx.android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.silverfix.dgdeditor"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java'] } }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testCompile('junit:junit:4.12')
    compile 'org.spockframework:spock-core:1.1-groovy-2.4-rc-3'
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:2.4.9:grooid'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'com.stepstone.stepper:material-stepper:1.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.0'
    compile 'jp.wasabeef:recyclerview-animators:2.2.5'
    compile 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:2.4.0'
    compile project(':javadgd')
    compile files('libs/commons-io-2.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/gson-2.8.0.jar')

}
```

And here is the project-level gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/shivasurya/materialsteppers" }
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.0'
        classpath 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-android-gradle-plugin:1.1.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url "http://dl.bintray.com/populov/maven" }
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I tried to change the Test Artifact inside Build Variants but I didn't find that option.

Comment: What is the output you see in the console? Based on the "Compilation  failed...." message you posted, you should be able to see more detail.

Comment: it's difficult to see the problem given the configuration you provided. however, you can find running spock tests in one of my sample applications: https://github.com/laenger/together-mvp. comparing this configuration to yours might help you. to execute tests use `gradlew example:testDebugUnitTest`

Comment: If you could provide the actual compilation errors I can give you more information.
But there are a couple of things that seem out of place. 
`sourceSets { main { java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java'] } }` this is the default behavior why are you adding this?
Spock rc-3 has some issues with byte buddy and would recommend updating to rc-4. Groovy 2.4.9 had an issue with it and I would recommend using 2.4.10.